# How to read large file to byte array?

Tags: android, arrays, out-of-memory

I have tried for **200 MB** of image file and converting it onto byte array but is crashed due to OOM, so how to read large file and converting into byte[]

**Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 210288697 byte allocation with 4108138 free bytes and 186MB until OOM**

```
byte[] fullyReadFileToBytes(File file) throws IOException {

        int size = (int) file.length();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
        byte tmpBuff[] = new byte[size];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {

            int read = fis.read(bytes, 0, size);
            if (read < size) {
                int remain = size - read;
                while (remain > 0) {
                    read = fis.read(tmpBuff, 0, remain);
                    System.arraycopy(tmpBuff, 0, bytes, size - remain, read);
                    remain -= read;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }

        return bytes;
    }
```

**NOTE: I have tried for 100MB and it is working perfect but in case of size greater than 150MB it's creating crash.**

Answer (score 2):

Use Http post multipart transfer i.e.

```
    ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;//1 mb buffer - set size according to your need
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Use volley multi-transfer request. It will keep track of failures
https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594

Comment: what is  bytesAvailable ?

Comment: I want to read complete file and divide into 5mb of byte[] so how can we do this ?

Comment: bytesavailable is remaining bytes which needs to be sent.. check updated code.

Comment: Thank i'll try it.

Comment: if we are stored byte array into memory than it still creating crash.

Comment: Thanks but i find another solution for this.

Comment: you need to break that into chunk of bytes and keep removing old allocated memory once it gets uploaded to server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170338/discussion-between-maveroid-and-vishal-patoliya-).

Comment: Can you share your solution

Comment: You can post your working solution as an answer to your post.

Answer (score -3):

The below code helps to compress the bitmap image and convert to string bytes.

```
 public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String temp = null;
        try {
            System.gc();
            temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
            b = baos.toByteArray();
            temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
        return temp;
    }
```